# Move react-native project to another machine

Tags: react-native

What's the proper procedure for moving an app (the entire project) still in development to another machine? I use bit-sync between two machines. Once it synced to machine B, I tried npm install, npm start, actually - I tried so many different things, I can't list them all. I'm sure the best way to do this is to use git. But I imagine there's still a procedure after using git. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Update:

I've tried moving my project to another machine two different ways. I've tried moving it via flashdrive and cloning a repository. I get the same output from xcode using both methods. Here is the output:

```
Ld /Volumes/Storage/DMA/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/weekdays-arzaqchtoxfjakbcqdknjpumqzwi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/weekdays.app/weekdays normal x86_64
    cd /Volumes/Development/React_Native_Workspace/weekdays/ios
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk -L/Volumes/Storage/DMA/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/weekdays-arzaqchtoxfjakbcqdknjpumqzwi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Volumes/Storage/DMA/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/weekdays-arzaqchtoxfjakbcqdknjpumqzwi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Volumes/Storage/DMA/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/weekdays-arzaqchtoxfjakbcqdknjpumqzwi/Build/Intermediates/weekdays.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/weekdays.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/weekdays.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime /Volumes/Storage/DMA/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/weekdays-arzaqchtoxfjakbcqdknjpumqzwi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a /Volumes/Storage/DMA/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/weekdays-arzaqchtoxfjakbcqdknjpumqzwi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTActionSheet.a /Volumes/Storage/DMA/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/weekdays-arzaqchtoxfjakbcqdknjpumqzwi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTGeolocation.a /Volumes/Storage/DMA/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/weekdays-arzaqchtoxfjakbcqdknjpumqzwi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTImage.a /Volumes/Storage/DMA/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/weekdays-arzaqchtoxfjakbcqdknjpumqzwi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTLinking.a /Volumes/Storage/DMA/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/weekdays-arzaqchtoxfjakbcqdknjpumqzwi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTNetwork.a /Volumes/Storage/DMA/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/weekdays-arzaqchtoxfjakbcqdknjpumqzwi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTSettings.a /Volumes/Storage/DMA/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/weekdays-arzaqchtoxfjakbcqdknjpumqzwi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTText.a /Volumes/Storage/DMA/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/weekdays-arzaqchtoxfjakbcqdknjpumqzwi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTVibration.a /Volumes/Storage/DMA/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/weekdays-arzaqchtoxfjakbcqdknjpumqzwi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTWebSocket.a -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Volumes/Storage/DMA/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/weekdays-arzaqchtoxfjakbcqdknjpumqzwi/Build/Intermediates/weekdays.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/weekdays.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/weekdays_dependency_info.dat -o /Volumes/Storage/DMA/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/weekdays-arzaqchtoxfjakbcqdknjpumqzwi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/weekdays.app/weekdays

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTEventEmitter", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTKeyboardObserver in libReact.a(RCTKeyboardObserver.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_RCTEventEmitter", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_RCTKeyboardObserver in libReact.a(RCTKeyboardObserver.o)
  "_RCTProfileTagAlways", referenced from:
      ___23-[RCTJSCExecutor setUp]_block_invoke_3 in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      ___23-[RCTJSCExecutor setUp]_block_invoke.235 in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      ___39-[RCTJSCExecutor registerNativeRequire]_block_invoke in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
  "operator delete[](void*)", referenced from:
      executeRandomAccessModule(RCTJSCExecutor*, unsigned int, unsigned long, unsigned long) in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
  "operator new[](unsigned long)", referenced from:
      executeRandomAccessModule(RCTJSCExecutor*, unsigned int, unsigned long, unsigned long) in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      -[RCTJavaScriptContext initWithJSContext:onThread:] in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      -[RCTJavaScriptContext init] in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      -[RCTJavaScriptContext invalidate] in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      _RCTNSErrorFromJSError in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      +[RCTJSCExecutor runRunLoopThread] in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      -[RCTJSCExecutor init] in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      -[RCTJSCExecutor context] in libReact.a(RCTJSCExecutor.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: In git, after cloning the project you just need to `npm install` `react-native start` and run the app from the native IDE. I'm not sure what part of that you are missing, besides maybe instaling `react-native-cli`

Comment: I updated my question with the output of the errors I'm getting in xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Biggest issue is ensuring all of the local requirements are met, like `node`, `npm`, etc.

All the stuff here:
facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content

Comment: I updated my question with the output of the errors I'm getting in xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out....

I was running Xcode 7.3.1 on machine A, and 7.3 on machine B. Apparently enough of a difference to cause the output above.